# Convert UItextview to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I've a `UITextView` with different properties like different color in the same text, font and size. I need to pass that text into a NSAttributedString variable.
With that code I'm not able to keep the properties of the text.
How can I do?

```
  let attr = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `attributedString` initializer of `NSAttributedString` and pass it your textview attributed text:

```
let attr = NSAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString:NSString = textView.text
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:myString.length)) 
textView.attributedText = myMutableString
```

TextView With RedFont Color :

[image]